# Which algebras of quaternion type do appear as blocks of group algebras?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, modular-representation-theory

A finite dimensional algebra $A$ is said to be of quaternion type (first defined by Erdmann?) when it is tame, symmetric and connected and furthermore the Cartan matrix is nonsingular and the stable Auslander-Reiten quiver consist only of tubes or rank $\leq 2$.
A complete classification up to Morita equivalence by quiver and relations is known over algebraically closed fields.

> Question 1: Is it known when such an algebra of quaternion type is a block of a group algebra? Is there a canonical group that has a given type as a block?

I did not find a reference for this but maybe even all such algebras appear as blocks.

> Question 2: While the algebra is tame, I heard that the problem to classify all indecomposable modules for the group algebra of the quaternions over a field of characteristic two is unsolved. Is this true more generally for any block of quaternion type?

> Question 3: Are they all periodic (if not,when are they periodic?), using their classification by quivers and relations? QPA tells me that the algebra of quaternion type $Q(2,B)_1^{(k,s)}(a,c)$ with $k=1,s=3,a=c=1$ is not periodic (the first simple is not periodic but the second one is with period 4) over the field with two elements. Im very confused now since I thought all those algebras are periodic with period 4.

Comment: Something is strange about the third question. In a symmetric algebra, the AR translate is the second syzygy, so the assumption about the AR quiver implies that the fourth syzygy of any non-projective module is isomorphic to the module itself.

PS. Did you ask Erdmann about these things?